# How to generate a function with multiple variables to fit experimental data?

Tags: analysis, algorithms, mathematical-modeling

I am researching methods to increase the accuracy of an algorithm that is currently used to analyse radiation patterns as they hit our sensor. 
(For the non-physicists, we will mainly see Alphas, Betas and Gammas which are the 3 most common radiation particles)

The 3 types of radiation make very distinctly different patterns on our sensor (which can be viewed graphically) which we call clusters (clusters of activated pixels).
I can retrieve lots of data about every cluster such as: Density, Roundness, Linearity, (and any others that you may think of?)

But my question is: **With a set of clusters from previous data sets that I can assign each as a Alpha, Beta or Gamma, is it possible to write an algorithm/equation which gives the most likely type particle for new clusters?**

For example here is some sample data (that ive made up on the spot, for the real algorithm I would try to use more like 500 pre-classified clusters each with around more like 6 variables each rather than the 3 shown here):

Roundness = 0.9, Density = 0.8, Radius = 4, Cluster Type = Alpha

Roundness = 0.5, Density = 0.2, Radius = 8, Cluster Type = Beta

Roundness = 0.3, Density = 0.4, Radius = 7, Cluster Type = Beta

Roundness = 1, Density = 1, Radius = 1, Cluster Type = Gamma

With this data, could we go about forming a method for determining the type of cluster that has the variables: Roundness = 0.7, Density = 0.3, Radius = 6?

If so, what or where should I research to learn more about such things?

I believe this is relevant in fitting algorithms and scalar fields but I am not certain as im still doing pre-university maths.

Any help in the right direction would be most appreciated, Thank You!

Comment: I am very interested in your question. However, I think answers to your question will come more readily if you give some very basic, concrete examples. Specifically, can you elaborate on the part of "With a set of clusters from previous data sets...." --- how do you represent a cluster and information about it?

Comment: Hi, ive tried to add some data that is typical of the clusters we expect to see - please comment again if you need anything else to help understand - your help is most appreciated!

Comment: I see the problem more clearly with your examples. Some questions: 1. When you say you have 500 pre-classified clusters, does this mean that you have a database of around 500/3 = 166 cluster signatures of Alpha particles; around 166 signatures from distinct Beta particles; and around 166 signatures from distinct Gamma particles?      2. Would you be inclined to call your mystery particle cluster (Roundness=0.7, Density=0.3, Radius=6) as the result of a Beta particle based on your example signatures?

Comment: 1. Yes this is what I mean however more clusters could be added to the database very easily indeed to whatever size database is needed to reduce uncertainty sufficiently.

Comment: 2. Yes I would call that a Beta, maybe I should just employ you! :P